# O que a expressão `system("pause")` faz?

Tags: c, sistema-operacional, processo

Para que serve o comando

```
system("pause");
```

?

Comment: Recomendo que comece lendo primeiro o que a função [`system`](https://devdocs.io/c/program/system) faz, depois tente entender o que o parâmetro `"pause"` significa.

Comment: Alguma das respostas resolveu sua dúvida? Acha que pode aceitar uma delas? Veja o [tour] como fazer isso, se ainda não o fez. Você ajudaria a comunidade identificando qual foi a melhor solução para você. Pode aceitar apenas uma delas. Mas pode votar em qualquer pergunta ou resposta que achar útil no site todo.

Answer (score 9):

A função [`system()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/system) chama o console do sistema operacional (se já não estiver rodando) e executa um comando neste aplicativo. No caso está chamando o comando `pause` do sistema operacional que fará o console ficar esperando por uma tecla e consequentemente sua aplicação esperará por isso também.

É usado para não deixar um teste rápido fechar. Quando se usa linha de comando para compilar não costuma ser necessário, o uso é para quem acostumou fazer uso de IDE. Recomenda-se usar outro mecanismo que não precise invocar o sistema operacional para obter o mesmo efeito, embora na maioria dos casos não faça diferença.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Vale lembrar que isso não vai funcionar em outros sistemas que não sejam o windows

Comment: @DenisRudneideSouza boa.

Comment: Isso! Como eu respondi numa pergunta sobre Python, onde usam o mesmo mecanismo - ou para pausa, ou para apagar a tela com "cls": é o equivalente a você quebrar a fechadura da sua porta, e achar que está ok chamar o chaveiro toda vez que for entrar ou sair de casa.  (uma chamada à função `gets()`, por exemplo, vai pausar o terminal até o usuário apertar enter do mesmo jeito)

Comment: Quanto a outros sistemas, os que usam o `os.system` em Python acham que por que dá pra escolher o comando entre "cls" e "clear" com `if sys.platform == 'nt':`,  acham que estão "abafando".

Comment: @jsbueno :D :D :D

Answer (score -2):

Basicamente o system("pause") vai mostrar o que se está a fazer no programa, sem ele, o programa corria sem parar (pause)

Comment: Oi - obrigado por sua contribuição e pelo espírito de compartilhamento. No entanto, acho que nesse caso, vale a pena descer mais a fundo nas implicações do que é chamar o  `system` - no caso, é usar o sistema operacional pra rodar todo um outro programa, separado do seu, para executar uma função trivial.